# Access denied due to CORS in SSRS for ASP .net core blazor app

Tags: reporting-services, cors, blazor-webassembly

I would like to get HTML from an SSRS report, using an HttpClient in .NET 5, like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new())
{
    using (var result = client.GetAsync($"http://localhost/ReportService?blablabla"))
    {
        if (result.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var win = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(win);
        }
    }
}
```

but my request is blocked by CORS:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/ReportService?blablabla' from
> origin 'https://localhost:44357' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have configured SSRS in SQL Server Management Studio like this:
[image: configuration].

The origin, 'localhost', is in the 'AccessControlAllowOrigin', so why is my request blocked?

thank you

EDIT I used [this page from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/server-properties-advanced-page-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15) to configure SSRS.

EDIT @sle: here is the result when I put the origin https://localhost:44357 in SSRS configuration property:
[image: result...it fails].

The error message  is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filled Access-Control-Allow-Origin with https://localhost:44357
For information, the server must returned on header the url of client.

Comment: have you got an idea of why is the entire uri not working? I can't see how to investigate further

Comment: ok, it works, just I had to be aware of caching in chrome.